# Function over distribution space

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, probability-theory

I am stuck with the following problem from research:

Let $X$ be a random variable with distribution function $F_X(x)$.

Let $y \in \mathbb{R}_+^n$ be a vector.

Let $\alpha$ be a function which depends on the probability distribution of $X$ and the vector $y$.
$\alpha: F_X \times \mathbb{R}_+^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

I have an optimization problem involving $\alpha$ and $y$.

What theory is available out there to handle such problems?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: As it stands, the fact that $\alpha$ takes in a special class of functions and a vector isn't telling us anything at all. Do you have any structure (any sort of convexity or something)? Also note that in the discrete case, $F_X$ is isomorphic to some vector in $\mathbb{R}^m_+$, so then standard theory applies.

Comment: Yes, $\alpha$ is convex is $F_X(x)$

Comment: Then good methods for your problem will probably exploit the fact that probability measures form an infinite dimensional *simplex*.

Comment: Do you have any reference for this kind of problems?

Comment: It is very difficult to say anything about such problems unless the particular form of the optimization problem is known, that is whether it is convex or concave, are the constraints linear etc.

Answer (score 0):

Without more structure to your problem, I can only shoot in the dark.

Perhaps we can write your problem as,

$$
\inf\limits_{f_j, y_i} \alpha(f_j, y_i) \\
s.t. \sum_j f_j = 1\\
b_k(y_l) = 0 \\
$$
where I have taken a discrete approximation of your density function for future limiting approximation.

Then we could write the Lagrangian,

$$
L(f_j, y_i, \lambda, \mu_k) = \alpha(f_j, y_i) + \lambda \left[ \sum_j (f_j) - 1 \right] + \sum_k \mu_k b_k(y_l)
$$

Then solve for whatever you want, as you haven't mentioned what, and somewhere along the way, take the limiting case $ f_j \rightarrow F_x $.

Clearly, I have ignored certain things, like the summation going to an integral, how $ f_j $ is represented, etc., but you should be able to figure this out.

I hope this helps. No promise it solves anything, just some ideas.